# botocore.exceptions.NoRegionError: You must specify a region

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, boto3

```
botocore.exceptions.NoRegionError: You must specify a region.
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I've already configured my AWS region in **`[~/.aws/config]`** but this problem arises again and again.
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: On what API call do you receive this message? Have you tried specifying a `region_name` while creating the `boto3.client('service-name', region_name='us-east-1')` to see whether that removes the exception?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein This fixed my error, even though this solution is not in [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transcribe/latest/dg/getting-started-python.html). Can you write an answer?

Answer (score 3):

```
$aws configure

AWS Access Key ID [****************LT6U]:
AWS Secret Access Key [****************iGrm]:
Default region name [ap-south-1]:
Default output format [json]:

specify: Default region name [ap-south-1]:
```

Mine is `ap-south-1`. Yours may be different.

Comment: "sudo aws configure" is distinct from "aws configure" and helped resolve this error for me - but I'm fairly certain I messed up my installation somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I hit the same issue. Make sure you have the right region name in your code like below.   You can find region names here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.RegionsAndAvailabilityZones.html

```
config = Config(
 region_name = 'us-east-1' # Choose a valid AWS Region.
)
```